# Why is spacing creating more than expected?

Tags: qt, qml, repeat

I recognized in my example a small gap between the repeated objects about one pixel more or less. Depending on the `property int size` this gap might change position. I also tested with `property double size` but this seem not changing the effect.

```
// FILE main.qml
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Rectangle {
  width: 640
  height: 320

  BarrierTape {}
}
```

```
// File BarrierTape.qml
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

Item {
  id: barrierTape
  property int size: 100
  x:200
  y:100
  ColumnLayout {
    spacing: barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    Repeater {
      model: 2
      Rectangle {
        width: barrierTape.size
        height: barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
        color: "#ffd100"
      }
    }
  }
  ColumnLayout {
    x: -barrierTape.size*3/4
    y: +barrierTape.size/2 * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    spacing: barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    Repeater {
      model: 2
      Rectangle {
        width: barrierTape.size
        height: barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
       color: "#ffd100"
      }
    }
  }
  ColumnLayout {
    x: +barrierTape.size*3/4
    y: -barrierTape.size/2 * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    spacing: barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    Repeater {
      model: 2
      Rectangle {
        width: barrierTape.size
        height: barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
        color: "#ffd100"
      }
    }
  }
  ColumnLayout {
    spacing: barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    y: +barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    Repeater {
      model: 2
      Rectangle {
        width: barrierTape.size
        height: barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
        color: "#222222"
      }
    }
  }
  ColumnLayout {
    x: -barrierTape.size * 3/4
    y: +barrierTape.size * 3/2 * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    spacing: barrierTape.size* Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    Repeater {
      model: 2
      Rectangle {
        width: barrierTape.size
        height: barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
        color: "#222222"
      }
    }
  }
  ColumnLayout {
    x: +barrierTape.size * 3/4
    y: +barrierTape.size * 1/2 * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    spacing: barrierTape.size* Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
    Repeater {
      model: 2
      Rectangle {
        width: barrierTape.size
        height: barrierTape.size * Math.sin(Math.PI/3)
        color: "#222222"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Further the code have a lot of Boilerplate and I don't know how to achieve the same behavior with less. I thought that creating first an item with all six rectangles and than repeating them would help, but if I put `Repeater` in one ColumnLayout seems to ignoring the `x` and `y` values. I struggle to refactor this file.

EDIT 1:

This is a sample of what it kind of should look like:

[image]

Comment: I might have already recognized the issue with the refactoring. I will update the question with a refactored code soon.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve? There might be a simpler solution. Maybe with an image? I've run your code, and the first thing I've noticed is that you could make a component of one of the strips and reuse it 3 times to further simplify the code.

Comment: The gaps might be due to rounding errors.

Comment: So you want to create a BarrierTape component. What should be the parameters? Height of each of the sections, number of sections, or should that depend on the actual height of the Barrier Tape?

Comment: I thought as well about a rounding error, but I am confused about since the rectangle size is calculated the same as the spacing. Or is this because js using weird not standard rounding?

Comment: Rounding seems to be the issue: If I only load two rectangles and repeat them once I get Four rectangles with size: 86.6... but the ColoumnLayout is 348 pixel large. I could limit the size to a matching value, but is their a different approach possible?

Comment: This is an inappropriate use of ColumnLayout.

Comment: @Stephen Quan Yes I realized this already. At the moment I am using iam_peter's approach with column and row with repeat and appropriate spacing.

Comment: Can I also recommend ShaderEffect?
The *size*, *color*, and *border color* will be more customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a slightly complicated Hexagon component which I did a while ago.

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 640
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: "#444444"

    property color color1: "#ffd100"
    property color color2: "#222222"

    property int hexRadius: 50
    property real hexInnerRadius: (Math.sqrt(3) / 2) * root.hexRadius
    property int spacing: 2

    component BarrierTape : Column {
        spacing: root.spacing
        Repeater {
            model: 4
            Item {
                width: root.hexRadius * 1.5
                height: 2 * root.hexInnerRadius

                Hexagon {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    width: 2 * root.hexRadius
                    height: 2 * root.hexRadius
                    radius: 10
                    fillColor: (index % 2 == 0) ? root.color1 : root.color2
                    antialiasing: true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Row {
        x: 100
        y: 150
        spacing: root.spacing
        Repeater {
            model: 4

            BarrierTape {
                y: index * -root.hexInnerRadius
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

`Hexagon.qml`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Shapes

Shape {
    id: root
    width: 200
    height: 200

    property int radius: 10
    property alias fillColor: path.fillColor

    layer.enabled: root.antialiasing
    layer.smooth: root.antialiasing
    layer.samples: root.antialiasing ? 4 : 0

    ShapePath {
        id: path
        joinStyle: ShapePath.MiterJoin
        strokeWidth: 0
        strokeColor: "transparent"
        startX: 0
        startY: 0
    }

    onRadiusChanged: {
        // Only construct polygon if radius changed from 0 to 1 or vice versa.
        if ((root.radius + root.__previousRadius) === 1)
            root.constructPolygon()

        root.__previousRadius = root.radius
    }
    Component.onCompleted: root.constructPolygon()

    property real __centerX: root.width / 2
    property real __centerY: root.height / 2
    property real __radius: Math.min(root.width, root.height) / 2

    property int __previousRadius: root.radius

    property int minRadius: 0
    property int maxRadius: root.__radius * Math.cos(root.toRadians(180.0 / 6))

    property int __actualRadius: Math.max(root.minRadius, Math.min(root.maxRadius, root.radius))

    function constructPolygon() {
        root.clearPathElements()

        if (root.radius === 0)
            root.constructNonRoundedPolygonPath()
        else
            root.constructRoundedPolygonPath()
    }

    function toRadians(degrees) {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180.0)
    }

    function constructNonRoundedPolygonPath() {
        for (var cornerNumber = 0; cornerNumber < 6; cornerNumber++) {
            let angleToCorner = root.toRadians(cornerNumber * (360.0 / 6))

            if (cornerNumber === 0) {
                path.startX = Qt.binding(function() {
                    return root.__centerX + root.__radius * Math.cos(0)
                })
                path.startY = Qt.binding(function() {
                    return root.__centerY + root.__radius * Math.sin(0)
                })
            } else {
                let pathLine = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.15; PathLine {}', path)
                pathLine.x = Qt.binding(function() {
                    return root.__centerX + root.__radius * Math.cos(angleToCorner)
                })
                pathLine.y = Qt.binding(function() {
                    return root.__centerY + root.__radius * Math.sin(angleToCorner)
                })
                path.pathElements.push(pathLine)
            }
        }

        // Close the polygon
        var pathLineClose = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.15; PathLine {}', path)
        pathLineClose.x = Qt.binding(function() { return path.startX } )
        pathLineClose.y = Qt.binding(function() { return path.startY } )
        path.pathElements.push(pathLineClose)
    }

    property real __halfInteriorCornerAngle: 90 - (180.0 / 6)
    property real __halfCornerArcSweepAngle: 90 - root.__halfInteriorCornerAngle
    property real __distanceToCornerArcCenter: root.__radius - root.__actualRadius /
                                               Math.sin(root.toRadians(root.__halfInteriorCornerAngle))

    function constructRoundedPolygonPath() {
        for (var cornerNumber = 0; cornerNumber < 6; cornerNumber++) {
            let angleToCorner = cornerNumber * (360.0 / 6)

            let pathArc = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.15; PathArc {
                                                property real centerX;
                                                property real centerY }', path)
            pathArc.centerX = Qt.binding(function() {
                return root.__centerX + root.__distanceToCornerArcCenter
                        * Math.cos(root.toRadians(angleToCorner))
            })
            pathArc.centerY = Qt.binding(function() {
                return root.__centerY + root.__distanceToCornerArcCenter
                        * Math.sin(root.toRadians(angleToCorner))
            })
            pathArc.x = Qt.binding(function() {
                return pathArc.centerX + root.__actualRadius
                        * (Math.cos(root.toRadians(angleToCorner + root.__halfCornerArcSweepAngle)))
            })
            pathArc.y = Qt.binding(function() {
                return pathArc.centerY + root.__actualRadius
                        * (Math.sin(root.toRadians(angleToCorner + root.__halfCornerArcSweepAngle)))
            })
            pathArc.radiusX = Qt.binding(function() { return root.__actualRadius })
            pathArc.radiusY = Qt.binding(function() { return root.__actualRadius })

            if (cornerNumber === 0) {
                path.startX = Qt.binding(function() {
                    return pathArc.centerX + root.__actualRadius
                            * (Math.cos(root.toRadians(angleToCorner - root.__halfCornerArcSweepAngle)))
                })
                path.startY = Qt.binding(function() {
                    return pathArc.centerY + root.__actualRadius
                            * (Math.sin(root.toRadians(angleToCorner - root.__halfCornerArcSweepAngle)))
                })
            } else {
                let pathLine = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.15; PathLine {}', path)
                pathLine.x = Qt.binding(function() {
                    return pathArc.centerX + root.__actualRadius
                            * (Math.cos(root.toRadians(angleToCorner - root.__halfCornerArcSweepAngle)))
                })
                pathLine.y = Qt.binding(function() {
                    return pathArc.centerY + root.__actualRadius
                            * (Math.sin(root.toRadians(angleToCorner - root.__halfCornerArcSweepAngle)))
                })
                path.pathElements.push(pathLine)
            }

            path.pathElements.push(pathArc)
        }

        // Close the polygon
        var pathLineClose = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.15; PathLine {}', path)
        pathLineClose.x = Qt.binding(function() { return path.startX} )
        pathLineClose.y = Qt.binding(function() { return path.startY} )
        path.pathElements.push(pathLineClose)
    }

    function clearPathElements() {
        for (var i = 0; i !== path.pathElements.length; ++i)
            path.pathElements[i].destroy()

        path.pathElements = []
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are on the right track about what I want to achieve. The Idea with the modulo seem right for my approach. But I fear what I want to achieve is not that simple. I've added a picture of what I want to achieve. So the rectangles are replaced by the hexagon, which might change a bit in future.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The positioning uses a bit of a hack, but it is working :)

Comment: Nice update. Original I was using Path as well, but switched to Image with SVG and changed the color of the SVG. But brilliant approach. Where did you solved the rounding issue?

Comment: My guess is that the rounding issue happend on your side due to the manually positioning of the `ColumnLayouts`. My solution only uses Positioner to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having great success at using SVG and a Button hack for rendering SVGs in different colors:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#444444" }

    Hex { x: 87.5; y: 150; color: "#ffd100" }
    Hex { x: 175; y: 100; color: "#ffd100" }
    Hex { x: 262.5; y: 50; color: "#ffd100" }

    Hex { x: 87.5; y: 450; color: "#222222" }
    Hex { x: 175; y: 400; color: "#222222" }
    Hex { x: 262.5; y: 350; color: "#222222" }

    Hex { x: 87.5; y: 350; color: "#ffd100" }
    Hex { x: 175; y: 300; color: "#ffd100" }
    Hex { x: 262.5; y: 250; color: "#ffd100" }

    Hex { x: 87.5; y: 250; color: "#222222" }
    Hex { x: 175; y: 200; color: "#222222" }
    Hex { x: 262.5; y: 150; color: "#222222" }
}

//Hex.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Item {
    property alias color: btn.icon.color
    Item {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200
        height: 200
        Button {
            id: btn
            background: Item { }
            icon.color: "#ffd100"
            icon.height: parent.height
            icon.width: parent.width
            icon.source: "Hex.svg"
        }
    }
}

//Hex.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-200 -200 400 400">
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="25" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 100 0 L 50 86.6 L -50 86.6 L -100 0 L -50 -86.6 L 50 -86.6 z" />
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?code=import%20QtQuick%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%202.15%0A%0APage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20background%3A%20Rectangle%20%7B%20color%3A%20%22%23444444%22%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%2087.5%3B%20y%3A%20150%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23ffd100%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%20175%3B%20y%3A%20100%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23ffd100%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%20262.5%3B%20y%3A%2050%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23ffd100%22%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%2087.5%3B%20y%3A%20450%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23222222%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%20175%3B%20y%3A%20400%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23222222%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%20262.5%3B%20y%3A%20350%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23222222%22%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%2087.5%3B%20y%3A%20350%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23ffd100%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%20175%3B%20y%3A%20300%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23ffd100%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%20262.5%3B%20y%3A%20250%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23ffd100%22%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%2087.5%3B%20y%3A%20250%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23222222%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%20175%3B%20y%3A%20200%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23222222%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Hex%20%7B%20x%3A%20262.5%3B%20y%3A%20150%3B%20color%3A%20%22%23222222%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2FHex.qml%0Aimport%20QtQuick%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%202.15%0A%0AItem%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20property%20alias%20color%3A%20btn.icon.color%0A%20%20%20%20Item%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anchors.centerIn%3A%20parent%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20height%3A%20200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Button%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20btn%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background%3A%20Item%20%7B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20icon.color%3A%20%22%23ffd100%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20icon.height%3A%20parent.height%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20icon.width%3A%20parent.width%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20icon.source%3A%20%22Hex.svg%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2FHex.svg%0A%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%22-200%20-200%20400%20400%22%3E%0A%3Cpath%20stroke%3D%22black%22%20stroke-width%3D%2225%22%20stroke-linejoin%3D%22round%22%20d%3D%22M%20100%200%20L%2050%2086.6%20L%20-50%2086.6%20L%20-100%200%20L%20-50%20-86.6%20L%2050%20-86.6%20z%22%20%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E)

Alternative to the Button icon.source, another way to recolor a SVG is to make use of `data-uri` and recolor the SVG by altering the color definitions within the SVG itself.

The following uses the `Image` component so it needs to set `sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)` to ensure that the SVG is upscaled property. The `color` property is pushed directly into the `data-uri` so that it changes both `stroke` and `fill` properties:

```
//Hex.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Image {
    width: 110
    height: 110
    property color color: "orange"
    sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
    source: `data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-115 -115 230 230">
<path stroke="%1" stroke-width="25" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="%1" d="M 100 0 L 50 86.6 L -50 86.6 L -100 0 L -50 -86.6 L 50 -86.6 z" />
</svg>
`.arg(color)
}
```

Comment: I used a different approach for coloring which worked fine: `ColorOverlay` and use the Image as `source` and `anchors.fill`. I keep in mind to setup the svg next time like yours instead of using rectangles as replacement. But it seems your approach struggles also with rounding errors.

Comment: You will soon learn that ColorOverlay isn't perfect since it uses OpenGL methods to recolour and image and QtGraphicalEffects is butchered in Qt6. The icon.source method is somewhat better in that it uses Qt internal svg rendering and recolouring.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of @iam_peter leaded me to the correct implementation. I accepted his answer, since it was based on my question the most accurate approach without an svg.

To complete this journey I provide my at the moment final solution:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import "Components"

Rectangle {
  width: 640
  height: 320
  color: "#444444"
  BarrierTape {}
}

//BarrierTape.qml
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

Item {
  id: root

  property color color1: "#ffd100"
  property color color2: "#222222"
  property real hexRadius: 100
  property real hexInnerRadius: (Math.sqrt(3)/2) * root.hexRadius

  component BarrierTapeRow: Row{
    id: hexRow
    property color rowColor: "pink"
    spacing: -1/4 * root.hexRadius
    Repeater {
      model: 4
      Hexagon_svg {
        y: index * -root.hexInnerRadius/2
        radius: root.hexRadius
        color: hexRow.rowColor
      }
    }
  }

  Column {
    x:100
    y:150
    spacing: 0
    Repeater {
      model: 5

      BarrierTapeRow {
        rowColor: (index % 2 == 0) ? root.color1 : root.color2
      }
    }
  }
}

//Hexagon_svg.qml
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Item {
  id: root
  property color color:"yellow"
  property real radius: 30
  height: Math.sqrt(3)/2 * root.radius
  width: root.radius

  Image {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    id: hexagonSvg
    source: Qt.resolvedUrl("Hex.svg")
    sourceSize.width: root.radius
    antialiasing: true
    visible: false
  }
  ColorOverlay {
    anchors.fill: hexagonSvg
    source: hexagonSvg
    color: root.color
    antialiasing: true
  }
}

//Hex.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-200 -200 400 400">
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="25" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 100 0 L 50 86.6 L -50 86.6 L -100 0 L -50 -86.6 L 50 -86.6 z" />
</svg>
```

Sadly I could not tested in the qml6online editor, because of the missing Package `QtGraphicalEffects`.

Result:

[image]